# Error GET "Url" net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (URL Rewrite Module Error.) en Publicacion de proyecto Angular 14 en Azure

Tags: azure

Estoy teniendo problemas a publicar mi proyecto `angular 14` en `Azure` en un app-service.

PROBLEMA:

Al momento de publicar y consultar la url de mi proyecfto me arroja los siguientes errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He consultado en diferentes fuentes y siempre sugieren lo mismo, agregar un archivo web.config, lo hice pero aun asi con la configuración no funciona.

Agrego el codigo de mi **`web.config`** y el comando que ejecuta el **pipeline** de `azure`:

Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
     <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"></httpErrors>
      <staticContent>
      <!-- Remove any potential Web Server Settings for Web Fonts to be used -->
      <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
      <remove fileExtension=".otf" />
      <remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
      <remove fileExtension=".js" />
      
      <!-- Define Web Font Mime Types that will be used -->
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="application/font-sfnt" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/font-sfnt" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svgz" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="application/javascript" />
    </staticContent>
      <rewrite>

        <rules>
          <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

Comando que ejecuta el pipeline azure:

```
"build-stg": "ng build --configuration stg "
```

En el archivo `angular.json` tengo la siguiente configuracion

```
"build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/web.config"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
              "src/assets/css/all.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/script.js"
            ],
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies":[
              "bs-stepper"
            ]
          },
```

Esto causa que las **img.svg** y el archivo **script.js** no funcionen en mi aplicacion.

Comment: Ya logre solucionar el problema, lo que estaba pasando era que al generar el build se estaba generando 2 web.config uno a nivel general y otro a nivel de assets lo que estaba generando conflictos , no me habia dado cuenta de esto ya que no tenia acceso al azure donde quedaba el artefacto.